# Entity Framework 4.1 Invalid object name 'us'

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

i've used ef power tools to reverse engineer a database. it created the classes and mapping using code first. not a problem there.

but when i try to run the following code:

```
using (var tmp= new PdbContext("nameofdb")
                {


                    try
                    {
                        tmp.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;


                        var tmpUsr = (from t in tmp.DadosUtilizadores
                                      where t.inactivo == false
                                      select t).ToList();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        tmp.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
                    }
                }
```

it throws an exception with the following text.

> Invalid object name 'us'

i've searched around here and found out that by doing the following would solve my problem:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
```

but it still doesn't resolve my problem.
so i checked the name of the table, and it's correct.
opened linqpad and tried to acess the data and it worked without any issues.
one thing caught my eye. the table has a trigger, will the trigger raise issues on this situation?

for better understanding the following code refers to my context class named PdbContext
and the mapping class named UtilizadoresMap.

PdbContext class

```
public class PdbContext:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Fltcl> FiltrosClientes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Fltst> FiltrosStocks { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Bo> DossiersInternos { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Cl> DadosClientes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Utilizadores> DadosUtilizadores { get; set; }

        public PdbContext(string valueConn):base(valueConn)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<PdbContext>(null);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FltstMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FltclMap());
            //modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ClMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UtilizadoresMap());

            //teste
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
            //
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

UtilizadoresMap class

```
public class UtilizadoresMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Utilizadores>
    {
        public UtilizadoresMap()
        {
         .......
         ToTable("us");
        }
     }
```

help would be appreciated
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

finally i've figured it out. the problem was that i using a providerconnectionstring to a database instead of loading only the string and let entity framework create it.